# Javascript group object of dates by weeks

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have data like this:

```
[
    {
        "time": "2021-07-28T18:16:23.994Z"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-07-29T18:16:23.994Z"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-08-01T15:01:40.267Z"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-08-02T15:01:40.267Z"
    },
    {
        "time": "2020-06-09T15:01:40.267Z"
    }
]
```

and I need a method that will return something like this:

```
{
    "2020": { // year
        "07/06-13/06": { // dates of the week
            "Tue": "2020-06-09T15:01:40.267Z" // day name at key
        }
    },
    "2021": {
        "25/07-31/07": {
            "Wed": "2021-07-28T18:16:23.994Z",
            "Thu": "2021-07-29T18:16:23.994Z"
        },
        "01/08-07/08": {
            "Sun": "2021-08-01T15:01:40.267Z",
            "Mon": "2021-08-02T15:01:40.267Z"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do this with momentjs and lodash/groupby but without success.. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said you tried with lodash, post the code of what you tried

Comment: show us some effort you have made so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a little bit ugly, but works:

```js
const datesArray = [
  {
    "time": "2021-07-28T18:16:23.994Z"
  },
  {
    "time": "2021-07-29T18:16:23.994Z"
  },
  {
    "time": "2021-08-01T15:01:40.267Z"
  },
  {
    "time": "2021-08-02T15:01:40.267Z"
  },
  {
    "time": "2020-06-09T15:01:40.267Z"
  }
]

function getWeeksRange(date) {
  const curr = new Date(date.time);
  const first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();
  const last = first + 6;
  const format = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
  var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toLocaleDateString("he-IL", format);
  var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toLocaleDateString("he-IL", format);
  ;
  return `${firstday.slice(0, 5).replaceAll('.', '/')}-${lastday.slice(0, 5).replaceAll('.', '/')}`
}

function groupDatesByWeek(dates) {

  const groupedDates = {}

  dates.forEach(date => {
    const range = getWeeksRange(date);
    const dayName = new Date(date.time).toString().split(' ')[0]
    if (!groupedDates[date.time.split('-')[0]]) {
      groupedDates[date.time.split('-')[0]] = {};
      groupedDates[date.time.split('-')[0]][range] = {};
    } else if (!groupedDates[date.time.split('-')[0]][range]) {
      groupedDates[date.time.split('-')[0]][range] = {};
    }
    groupedDates[date.time.split('-')[0]][range][dayName] = date.time;
  })

 return groupedDates;
}
console.log(groupDatesByWeek(datesArray))
```